# How to write information from a list to a csv file using csv DictWriter?

Tags: python, csv

Using the `csv` module , Ive been trying to pass / write information from a list  to a csv file  in `python`using the dictwriter and im getting a strange error , witch will be under the actual code. I want to know whats , the error in the code , and how can we fix it.

```
import csv 

names = ['kisha' ,'smith'  , 'kishasmith@gmail.com', 40000  ,  '1-1-2029'   ,'janitor' ]

with open('employees.csv' , 'w')as employee_file:
     fieldnames2 = ['first' , 'last' , 'email' , 'salary' , 'DOB' , 'occupation']
     csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(employee_file , fieldnames = fieldnames2 , delimiter = ',')
     csvwriter.writeheader()
     for info in names:
        csvwriter.writerow(info)
```

Ive seen other questions related to this topic but nun are applicable to me.

## ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kxrk\Downloads\Codes\Employee project\new.py", line 10, in <module>
    csvwriter.writerow(info)
  File "C:\Users\Kxrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\Kxrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: `names` must be a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerow()` function of the `csv.DictWriter` class expects the parameter as `dict`, whereas you are passing string to it. It is clearly mentioned in [`csv.DictWriter` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) which says:

> Create an object which operates like a regular writer but maps
>   dictionaries onto output rows. The fieldnames parameter is a sequence
>   of keys that identify the order in which values in the dictionary
>   passed to the **writerow()** method are written to the csvfile.

In order to make it work, pass the `dict` object *(with the mapping between the csv headers and the corresponding column value)*. For example:

```
import csv

names = ['kisha' ,'smith'  , 'kishasmith@gmail.com', 40000  ,  '1-1-2029'   ,'janitor' ]
fieldnames2 = ['first' , 'last' , 'email' , 'salary' , 'DOB' , 'occupation']

# for creating the dictionary object mapping "names" and "fieldnames2"
my_names_dict = dict(zip(fieldnames2, names))

with open('/path/to/my_file.csv' , 'w')as employee_file:
     csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(employee_file , fieldnames = fieldnames2 , delimiter = ',')
     csvwriter.writeheader()
     csvwriter.writerow(my_names_dict)
```

Above code will create a file `/path/to/my_file.csv` with the content as:

```
first,last,email,salary,DOB,occupation
kisha,smith,kishasmith@gmail.com,40000,1-1-2029,janitor
```

Comment: thanks that helped alot , using the zip function to create tuples and using the dict function to create a dictionary based on the firstindex being the key and the second  being the value, am i correct?

Comment: @CodingRonald Nope, `zip(fieldnames2, names)` creates as tuple by merging both the lists together. Where as `dict(my_tuple)` will create the `dict` object with the 0th index in tuple as key and 1st index as it's value. Run it and try by yourself. You'll get the idea :)

Comment: lol thanks litterally what i just said  , without all the explanation , but thanks for breaking it down , we need more comments like this for those who will later view.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `info` should be a dictionary, from a list of dictionaries. It's currently a string...

Anyway, your dataset is more suited for a simple `csv.writer`

I've changed `names` to a list of lists, containing all the rows, changed `DictWriter` to `writer`.
Then dropped `writeheader` for `writerow` with the title. Also used `writerows` on the list of lists for better speed (avoids a loop):

```
import csv

names = [ ['kisha' ,'smith'  , 'kishasmith@gmail.com', 40000  ,  '1-1-2029'   ,'janitor' ],
         # more employees here
          ]

with open('employees.csv' , 'w', newline="") as employee_file:
     fieldnames2 = ['first' , 'last' , 'email' , 'salary' , 'DOB' , 'occupation']
     csvwriter = csv.writer(employee_file , delimiter = ',')
     csvwriter.writerow(fieldnames2)
     csvwriter.writerows(names)
```

Also note that you need `newline=""` (python 3) or your csv file will have a blank line every other line on windows.

Comment: yea , thanks for the heads up , this was a test ,  but to answer to your response ,  i was using the dictwriter over simply using writer , to make the data easy to access, but anyways that was a great solution thanks.

Comment: choosing which writer really depends on your input. Your input seemed more adapted (in your test, that is) to a simple `writer`